# Querying XML nodes using T-SQL getting wrong result set

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to extract the records from the an XML file but I am getting records where the records do NOT meet the criteria in the WHERE clause.

Here is my T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @StartLossDate date = '2018-12-15';
DECLARE @EndLossDate date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE());

SELECT @StartLossDate as StartLossDate, @EndLossDate as EndLossDate;

-- Get result set.
SELECT DISTINCT t.SysDate, t.PolicySysID, t.PolicyNo
    a.b.value('(LossDt)[1]','date') as LossDate
    , a.b.value('(ClaimNumber)[1]','varchar(max)') as ClaimNumber
    , d.e.value('(LossTypeCd)[1]','varchar(max)') as LossTypeCd
FROM #tempXMLRecords t
    CROSS APPLY t.xmlPlus.nodes('ISO/PassportSvcRs/Reports/Report/ReportData/ISO/PassportSvcRs/PassportInqRs/Match/Claim/Loss') as a(b)
    CROSS APPLY t.xmlPlus.nodes('ISO/PassportSvcRs/Reports/Report/ReportData/ISO/PassportSvcRs/PassportInqRs/Match/Claim/Payment') as d(e)
WHERE a.b.value('(LossDt)[1]','date') BETWEEN @StartLossDate AND @EndLossDate
AND d.e.value('(LossTypeCd)[1]','varchar(4)') = 'TOWL'
ORDER BY PolicySysID asc;
```

The results that I'm getting is:
[image]

The TOP 2 records above do NOT HAVE a LossTypeCd of TOWL in the XML.

Any help/direction would be appreciated. I guess I'm confused on how the node definition in the CROSS APPLY is supposed to work.

Here is my XML:

```
<ISO>
    <PassportSvcRs>
        <Reports>
          <Report>
            <ReportData>
              <ISO>
                <PassportSvcRs>
                  <PassportInqRs>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>                       
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2020-11-01</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>7842198101J20110105</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>78</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2020-10-28</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>7842198101J20102805</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>78</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2020-10-03</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>7842198101J20100305</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>78</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>                      
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2019-10-21</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>66203023279998</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>3963</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>                      
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2019-05-26</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>PTX19035829</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>COMP</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>COMP</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2018-10-16</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>0522909605</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>UM</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>UM</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2017-11-05</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>0481373215</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>23</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2017-10-07</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>0478275043</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>2866</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>RENT</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>RENT</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>W</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2017-06-09</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>JM177514</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>2374</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                    <Match>
                      <Claim>
                        <Loss>
                          <LossDt>2016-01-16</LossDt>
                          <ClaimNumber>7842382435D16011605</ClaimNumber>
                        </Loss>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>4175</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                        <Payment>
                          <CoverageCd>RENT</CoverageCd>
                          <LossTypeCd>RENT</LossTypeCd>
                          <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                          <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                        </Payment>
                      </Claim>
                    </Match>
                  </PassportInqRs>
                </PassportSvcRs>
              </ISO>
            </ReportData>
          </Report>
        </Reports>
    </PassportSvcRs>
</ISO>
```

Thanks.

Comment: With no example XML there's not a lot we can tell you here. Provide a [mre].

Comment: I do not believe the query contains logic to ensure that the payment data and loss data belong to the same claim. Perhaps you need to first select Claim nodes in the CROSS APPLY and then select Loss/LossDate, Loss/ClaimNumber, and Payment/LossTypeCd from the selected claims.

Comment: @TN, thanks.  I'll try that.  Appreciate the suggestion. I just attached the XML if you don't mind taking a look.  Thanks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Got it.  Thank @YitzhakKhabinsky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe the query contains logic to ensure that the payment data and loss data belong to the same claim.

Looking at the freshly posted XML, I see that claims may contain multiple payments, but (apparently) only one Loss. You may need one cross apply to select the claims, and then a second cross apply to select payments relative to each claim.

The following stripped down query seems to work.

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = '...' -- See posted XML above
DECLARE @tempXMLRecords TABLE(xmlPlus XML)
INSERT @tempXMLRecords VALUES (@Xml)
SELECT
    c.value('(Loss/LossDt)[1]','date') as LossDate
    , c.value('(Loss/ClaimNumber)[1]','varchar(max)') as ClaimNumber
    , p.value('(LossTypeCd)[1]','varchar(max)') as LossTypeCd
FROM @tempXMLRecords t
CROSS APPLY t.xmlPlus.nodes('ISO/PassportSvcRs/Reports/Report/ReportData/ISO/PassportSvcRs/PassportInqRs/Match/Claim') as C(c)
CROSS APPLY c.nodes('./Payment') as P(p)
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: what you suggested is exactly what I did.  I very much appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Good answer. According to OP's requirements, you probably want a predicate in the first `.nodes` like this `Match/Claim[Payment/LossTypeCd[text() = "TOWL"]]`. You can shorten slightly the second one with just `c.nodes('Payment')`. Adding `/text()` to the `.value` functions will make them more performant.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It supports multiple payments for a single claim.

When it is happening the ***LossTypeCd*** column will have multiple claims.

If you don't need that it is very easy to adjust having just one single claim in that column.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmlPlus XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmlPlus) VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ISO>
    <PassportSvcRs>
        <Reports>
            <Report>
                <ReportData>
                    <ISO>
                        <PassportSvcRs>
                            <PassportInqRs>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2020-11-01</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>7842198101J20110105</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>78</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2020-10-28</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>7842198101J20102805</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>78</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2020-10-03</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>7842198101J20100305</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>78</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2019-10-21</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>66203023279998</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>3963</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2019-05-26</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>PTX19035829</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>COMP</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>COMP</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2018-10-16</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>0522909605</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>UM</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>UM</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2017-11-05</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>0481373215</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>TOWL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>TOWL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>23</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2017-10-07</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>0478275043</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>2866</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>RENT</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>RENT</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>W</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2017-06-09</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>JM177514</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>2374</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                                <Match>
                                    <Claim>
                                        <Loss>
                                            <LossDt>2016-01-16</LossDt>
                                            <ClaimNumber>7842382435D16011605</ClaimNumber>
                                        </Loss>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>COLL</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>4175</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                        <Payment>
                                            <CoverageCd>RENT</CoverageCd>
                                            <LossTypeCd>RENT</LossTypeCd>
                                            <ClaimStatusCd>C</ClaimStatusCd>
                                            <LossPaymentAmt>0</LossPaymentAmt>
                                        </Payment>
                                    </Claim>
                                </Match>
                            </PassportInqRs>
                        </PassportSvcRs>
                    </ISO>
                </ReportData>
            </Report>
        </Reports>
    </PassportSvcRs>
</ISO>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @StartLossDate DATE = '2018-12-15'
    , @EndLossDate DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

SELECT ID
    , c.value('(Loss/LossDt/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS LossDate
    , c.value('(Loss/ClaimNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ClaimNumber
    , c.query('data(Payment/LossTypeCd)').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS LossTypeCd
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmlplus.nodes('/ISO/PassportSvcRs/Reports/Report/ReportData/ISO/PassportSvcRs/PassportInqRs/Match/Claim') AS t(c)
WHERE c.value('(Loss/LossDt/text())[1]', 'DATE') BETWEEN @StartLossDate AND @EndLossDate
    AND c.exist('Payment/LossTypeCd[./text()="TOWL"]') = 1;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+
| ID |  LossDate  |     ClaimNumber     | LossTypeCd |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 | 2020-11-01 | 7842198101J20110105 | TOWL       |
|  1 | 2020-10-28 | 7842198101J20102805 | TOWL       |
|  1 | 2020-10-03 | 7842198101J20100305 | TOWL       |
+----+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Melinda, Is your lowest denominator a **Payment/LossTypeCd**? I used **ClaimNumber**  for that.

Comment: @DaleK, I did. Thanks

Comment: As @TN had suggested, the Claim is what I used. I had to go up one level in the XML to get all the pertinent data.  I'm NOT sure why my question got a -1.  I guess it wasn't useful(?).

Comment: I think it got downvoted before you added the sample data and the person who did the downvote probably hasn't come back and seen that you improved it.